# go back button needs reload to show data

Tags: javascript, php

I am making a rental car application, and I am having a problem with going back to edit previous data. My application has 4 steps: First step - choose car type and location, second step - display all cars with those parameters and choose one of them, third step - show detailed information about the car chosen, and here I have an edit 2 edit button which sends me back to first and second steps. The problem is that when I click edit it shows me : *This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you will repeat any action this page previously performed.*

```
<a href="javascript:history.back()" title="">Edit</a>
```

I am not saving the data filled in in steps 1 and 2 in the session (only id of user). Instead the data of 1 step such as location and date are sent to 4 step with input type="hidden" at each form.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215637/navigate-back-with-php-form-submission

Comment: This is because the previous page submitted its data with `post` instead of `get`

Comment: @DHS so I should use get instead of post? is there any other solution?

Comment: I am actually not quite sure what you want to archieve? If you go back in history you get the previous page and you can edit that. Is that what you want? If so, yes then you can use `get` if it is an option (remember security). Otherwise you may think of doing it in another way completely depending on what you want.