# Android Webview gives net::ERR_CACHE_MISS message

Tags: android, android-studio, webview

**2023 Edit: This question was from 2015. You may be able to find more suitable answers elsewhere.**

I built a web app and wants to create an android app that has a webview that shows my web app. After following the instructions from Google Developer to create an app, I successfully installed it on my phone with Android 5.1.1.

However, when I run the app for the first time, the webview shows the message:

> Web page not available
>
> The Web page at [Lorem Ipsum URL] could not be loaded as:
>
> net::ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: Maybe this link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664146/android-4-4-giving-err-cache-miss-error-in-onreceivederror-for-webview-back

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Answers assembled! I wanted to just combine all the answers into one comprehensive one.

**1.** Check if `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` is present in `manifest.xml`. **Make sure that it is nested under `<manifest>` and not `<application>`**. Thanks to [sajid45](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6629042/sajid45) and [Liyanis Velazquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9701254/liyanis-velazquez)

**2.** Ensure that you are using `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` instead of the deprecated `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet"/>`. Much thanks to [alan_shi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133469/alan-shi) and [creos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3903990/creos).

**3.** If minimum version is below KK, check that you have

```
if (18 < Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ){
    //18 = JellyBean MR2, KITKAT=19
    mWeb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
```

or

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}
```

because proper webview is only added in KK (SDK 19). Thanks to [Devavrata](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1310448/devavrata), [Mike ChanSeong Kim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6572459/mike-chanseong-kim) and [Liyanis Velazquez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9701254/liyanis-velazquez)

**4.** Ensure that you don't have `webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads (false);`. Thanks to [TechNikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2197176/technikh) for pointing this out.

**5.** If all else fails, make sure that your Android Studio, Android SDK and the emulator image (if you are using one) is updated. And if you are still meeting the problem, just open a new question and make a comment below to your URL.

Comment: If all else fails, uninstall and reinstall the app inside your emulator.

Answer (score 484):

I solved the problem by changing my **`AndroidManifest.xml`**.

old  : `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.internet"/>`
**new: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`**

Comment: man, you saved my day! After upgrade to Cordova 7.0.1 no XHR was working. I manually added this to the manifest and...boom! :)

Comment: No internet, but INTERNET! The BIG one! :)

Answer (score 33):

For anything related to the internet, your app must have the internet permission in ManifestFile. I solved this issue by adding permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 30):

I tried above solution, but the following code help me to close this issue.

```
if (18 < Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ){
    //18 = JellyBean MR2, KITKAT=19
    mWeb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}
```

Comment: Where is this `Build` and `mweb` vars?

Comment: @MichaelPacheco Build is from Android System and mweb is the webview object

Answer (score 10):

Use

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }
```

It should solve the error.

Comment: This answer helped me a lot, Thanks. But I use `WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE`

Answer (score 9):

Also make sure your code doesn't have true for setBlockNetworkLoads

```
webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads (false);
```

Answer (score 7):

I ran to a similar problem and that was just because of the extra spaces:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET "/>`

which when removed works fine:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`