# Android Webview Unable to Upload Captured Image In android 5+? But its working In some Devices

Tags: android, webview, camera

I Followed [this](https://github.com/mgks/Os-FileUp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/inf/os/fileup/MainActivity.java) To Capture Images from Webview and Upload

I got A page Reload Error After Capturing Image

After Adding this

```
if ((savedInstanceState == null)&&(URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)))
    {
        webView.loadUrl(url);
    }
```

Its working fine in some Devices....

But for some devices I am getting That error My webpage is not responding After Capturing Image I am Getting Error **`net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`**

But In some Devices its working fine whether It may be android `5x` or `6x` its working fine And file is uploading with Default Camera Capture...

Please Help me on this kind

**Update 1**

I have Given it like this

```
if((savedInstanceState == null)) {
        mWebView.loadUrl(url);
    }
    else {
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/no-network-icons/512/No_Network_an-512.png");
    }
```

So Here I understand Aftere Capture its not working It is Loading nothing now After Adding Else.... It is going to that link...

please Help me on this **This error is comming in some devices only** Remaning are working fine please help me

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637654/android-webview-gives-neterr-cache-miss-message

Comment: Sorry that not the issue...I have Given Permission and I can Able to Open Page... And if I add this `WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE`There is no Option to Upload

Comment: Can you post your LogCat log?

Comment: What sort of devices does it not work on. Give us a short list with device types and android version.

Comment: its working in non branded devices and mostly not working in Samsung,Sony,Lg etc in all android 5+,6+ versions.. where as its working with Mi, Huwai ,azus