# App shows black screen for half a second and crashes without error

Tags: android, android-studio

I just started to learn android app development. I try to create a very simple app which just redirects the user to our homepage in fullscreen mode.

But if I start the app, then a black window shows for less than a half second and the app closes.

I have no clue how to debug/fix this, I hope someone can help a beginner out! Thx!

**app\src\main\res\layout\activity_fullscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <WebView android:id="@+id/botecView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content" />

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <FrameLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?metaButtonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**app\src\main\java\com\example\botec\FullscreenActivity.java**

```
package com.example.botec;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;

    private View mContentView;
    private View mControlsView;
    private boolean mVisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mVisible = true;

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.
        //findViewById(R.id.dummy_button).setOnTouchListener(mDelayHideTouchListener);

        WebView botecView = findViewById(R.id.botecView);
        botecView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        botecView.loadUrl("https://www.botec.de");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
            mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
            mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in delay milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Logcat (empty):

[image]

Comment: "I just started to learn android app development", "I have no clue how to debug this", Hint: use **Logcat**.

Comment: Ok, I get `7847-7847/com.huawei.hwdetectrepair E/SmartNotifyService: intent null in onStartCommand`. I have no clue where the onStartCommand is located

Comment: This seems not related to **your** current application. Hint: use **filter** to find the logcat generated by _current_ application, and catch the most important error generated at _current_ crash realtime. Then you may edit the question to show the logcat.

Comment: @GenoChen how do I know if it is related to my current application or not?

Comment: Set the filter condition, produce the crash, capture the logcat generated during crash on time, use it to debug, or use it to ask others to help you.

Comment: @GenoChen ok I undertand you fully. there is no log output at all.

Comment: You can choose "show current application" (just this meaning, maybe not precise text) in the filter condition, lies in the top right corner in logcat window in Android Studio.

Comment: @GenoChen, Yes thanks, but there is no log output at all, even on verbose.

Comment: It is very very very strange to have no logcat. Have you connected that device to Android Studio (actually, the tool `adb` in Android SDK)? And did you choose the right device and the right application in the top left corner of logcat window in Android Studio?

Comment: @GenoChen, yes, look at the screenshot in my question.

Comment: You choose the wrong application in the top left window. Not `com.huawei.detect...`, but (very possible) `com.example.botec`.

Comment: @GenoChen, this is the only available option.

Comment: Ouch... Is your `packageName` (in `src/build.gradle`) defined as `com.huawei.detect...`? I think this is nearly impossible. But why you can't see your current application leads to a very strange problem. Would you try to run this application again **via Run button in Android Studio**, and **keep the logcat window opened**, to see if the current application changes? (And the crash logcat may occur, if everything are running as expected).

Comment: @GenoChen, there is no folder called `src`

Comment: Sorry for my failure. It may be `app/build.gradle` or `app/src/build.gradle`, I forgot that. But this maybe not so important at this time. Just a small guess.

Comment: Logcat -> dropdown in the right select : Error. Then post a screenshot of the problem that causes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems like that there was unneeded code. I changed it to this:

**app\src\main\res\layout\activity_fullscreen.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->
    <WebView android:id="@+id/botecView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:gravity="center" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**app\src\main\java\com\example\botec\FullscreenActivity.java**

```
package com.example.botec;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * Some older devices needs a small delay between UI widget updates
     * and a change of the status and navigation bar.
     */
    private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
    private boolean mVisible;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        mVisible = true;

        WebView botecView = findViewById(R.id.botecView);
        botecView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        botecView.loadUrl("https://www.botec.de");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void toggle() {
        if (mVisible) {
            hide();
        } else {
            show();
        }
    }

    private void hide() {
        // Hide UI first
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.hide();
        }
        mVisible = false;

        // Schedule a runnable to remove the status and navigation bar after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mShowPart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHidePart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed removal of status and navigation bar

            // Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
            // and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
            // at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
        }
    };

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void show() {
        // Show the system bar
        mVisible = true;

        // Schedule a runnable to display UI elements after a delay
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHidePart2Runnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mShowPart2Runnable, UI_ANIMATION_DELAY);
    }

    private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Delayed display of UI elements
            ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            if (actionBar != null) {
                actionBar.show();
            }
        }
    };

    private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in delay milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

Now if I execute my code, then I get a page saying "Website not available. The website under https://www.botec.de/ could not load because: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" (solution for this new problem can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30637654/android-webview-gives-neterr-cache-miss-message)).

So the problem with the blackscreen and "crash" or rather closing of the app, was because of that unnecessary code which was there after creating a new empty fullscreen project.

Answer (score 0):

I have two options for the error that you've showed in the comments: `7847-7847/com.huawei.hwdetectrepair E/SmartNotifyService: intent null in onStartCommand`

**First one:**

You should extend your check to this:

```
if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null) {
```

If you want to add an Action to your intent you need to call [setAction()][1]:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainService.class);
i.setAction("foo");
startService(i);
```

**Second one:**

Just try adding this simple check :

```
intent.getAction() != null
```

Hope that helps. Let me know :)

Comment: Hi @android, thx for your answer. Where is this code located at? I cant find the word `intent` in my code? I just started a new empty fullscreen project, I don't believe that it has already bugs?