# Android WebView shows `net::ERR_CACHE_MISS` message sometimes

Tags: android, networking, webview, browser-cache

I've read answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60647176/535374 . In my case it is different because this is an app in production and customers randomly report this error. Not a 100% re-produce one. Is there anything I can do to debug the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Add internet permission in manifest file

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```