# Not able to load Webview (permissions added)

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to create a simple App that loads a url into a webview. However, I keep getting `net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`. I've added the relevant permission for the internet which seemed the most common cause for the error.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static String TAG = "Main";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new myWebviewClient());

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.foodport.co.in");

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public class myWebviewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        Log.i(TAG, "onReceivedError "+ errorCode);
    }
}
```

I've added `<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.INTERNET"/>` to the manifest file.

Any help? The only clue I have is that a had another app using the same package name on the same phone, but that also that all the permissions. 
I'm checking on a phone which runs Android 4.4, I checked [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664146/android-4-4-giving-err-cache-miss-error-in-onreceivederror-for-webview-back) but I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: "I keep getting net::ERR_CACHE_MISS" -- where are you getting this? In LogCat? In `onReceivedError()`? Somewhere else?

Comment: Yep on `onRecievedError()`, Also on the webview itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've added  to the manifest file

Android is case-sensitive. Please edit this to be `android.permission.INTERNET`.

Comment: Wow, didn't think that would be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
}
  or use this code 
 webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Comment: check this one ::: webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(android.webkit.WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

Answer (score -2):

You have to set the  **`WebView webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);`**
   in **OnCreate** method **instead of onStart**
after setting layout for the activity setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout);

Comment: As per the activity life-cycle, `onCreate()` gets called first. After that `onStart()` gets called. So, it's completely fine to instantiate the web view in `onStart()` as the layout is already loaded.