# $http requests failing on Ionic after 'ionic build android'

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have been testing my app using ionic serve while developing and everything is working fine. I am now trying to export the apk using ionic build android, then storing the file 'android-debug.apk' on my web server and downloading it via a phone's browser and installing it to test it in the real world.

The app installs OK, but won't let me make any $http requests. I have installed the plugin cordova-plugin-whitelist, and also added the following to my config.xml file:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
      <access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
      <allow-intent href="*" />
      <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
      <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
      <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
      <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
      <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
      <platform name="android">
          <allow-intent href="market:*" />
      </platform>
      <platform name="ios">
          <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
          <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
      </platform>
```

As well as that, I have added this into my main index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Can someone tell me why the requests are still failing please?

I have tested on 2 different servers, both have CORS enabled and this has been verified using Postman.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

My $http request looks like this:

```
$http.get('http://url.com/request').then(function(res) {
                    console.log('success');
                    console.log(res);
                }, function(res) {
                    console.log('error');
                    console.log(res);
                });
```

After enabling remote chrome debugging, I get an error alert, following by an object which has:

```
data: null,
status: 0,
statusText: ""
```

Comment: You can inspect the hybrid app using chrome and it can show you the error.connect your phone to your system and inspect the app.

Comment: I just tried that and the error I get is: `POST: http//url.com net::ERR_CACHE_MISS`...doesn't give much more information though

Comment: In the network tab, the request says `(failed) xhr`

Comment: copy the url and try to run it  through postman in your system. see if you can get the response.

Comment: This is possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664146/android-4-4-giving-err-cache-miss-error-in-onreceivederror-for-webview-back

Comment: I've updated my question. The request works fine using Postman, but just not in the app

Comment: May be its  a CORS issue

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I needed to add:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

into platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml. Working OK now!

Comment: I have the permission in the AndroidManifest.xml but still failing. Any other pointers? its been 2 days but still not able to resolve the issue

Comment: This happened to me after I upgrading (/generally messing about with) cordova versions - maybe that declaration was added in Cordova 7?  Doing "cordova platform remove android" then  "cordova platform add android" fixed it properly for me...