# Ionic app working on browser but not on device?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have designed app using ionic and angularjs. Earlier the app was working fine but now i have changed the api ....the app working on browser but not on device...its functionalities not working on device..
before changed the api(app working on device):

```
var CONSTANTS = "http://ip_address/api/";
var api =  CONSTANTS+'api.php?method=register' + '&user_registration=';

$http.post(api, {username : username,email : useremail,pwd : userpassword}).success(function(response) {   

    if( response[0].status == 1){               

        $cordovaToast.showShortBottom('Successfully Registered').then(function(success) {
            // success
        }, function (error) {
            // error
        });  

        document.getElementById('user_email').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('user_email').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('user_email').innerHTML = "";
        $state.go('auth.login');

    }else if( response[0].status == 0){

        $cordovaToast.showLongBottom('Existing User or Invalid Data').then(function(success) {
            // success
        }, function (error) {
            // error
        });  

    }else {
        //console.log('Error');
    }

}, function(err) {
    // console.log(err);
});
```

after changing the api in the code(app not working on device):

```
var CONSTANTS = "https://www.test.com/api/";
var api =  CONSTANTS+'api.php?method=register' + '&user_registration=';

$http.post(...)... // Same as above
```

Comment: Try investigating if request is not failing. There is some remote debugging as far as I remember for Ionic on devices.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsmobile.cordova-tools

Comment: how to use https in ionic?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937038/http-requests-failing-on-ionic-after-ionic-build-android

Comment: this might help

Comment: Hello,

i have designed an app using ionic and angularJS. the application is working fine when i am using http in api's. i wanted to use https in api's for security purpose . how can i make https request to web server via SSL in ionic framework.


Any help  appreciated.

Thanks in advance.