# ERR_CACHE_MISS in WebView Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, webview

I 'm trying to do a simple browser AndroidStudio , but websites do not open ( error : net :: ERR_CACHE_MISS ).

I tried this :

[Android 4.4 giving ERR_CACHE_MISS error in onReceivedError for WebView back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664146/android-4-4-giving-err-cache-miss-error-in-onreceivederror-for-webview-back)

but it did not help me .

my ActivityMain:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText pole;
Button przycisk;
WebView przegladarka;
public String adres;

public void Wyszukaj(View v){
    adres =  pole.getText().toString();
    przegladarka.loadUrl(adres);
}






@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    przycisk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.przycisk);
    pole = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pole);
    przegladarka = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.przegladarka);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        przegladarka.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    }

    przegladarka.setWebViewClient(new ModifiedWebViewClient());
    przegladarka.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    przegladarka.loadUrl("http://google.com");


}


private class ModifiedWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to your manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```