# Android net::ERR_CACHE_MISS on debug output

Tags: android, google-chrome, xamarin.android

I realise that this question has been asked (and solved) here before, however the most frequent and obvious solution, which is to place

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

in the Android.Manifest.xml file, does not work for me.

I have double checked that I have not placed this within the manifest's

```
<application />
```

tag, yet it still doesn't work.

I'm running Android 9 (Pie) as the target version, but I can't find any breaking changes with that API which may give this error. I have also cleared the cache on my Google Chrome app, which the app is using as it's default Webview.

Comment: You can check this answer of thread about your error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25664146/android-4-4-giving-err-cache-miss-error-in-onreceivederror-for-webview-back, If you running your code in android 8.1, if you have the same issue?

Comment: thanks @LeonLu-MSFT, I had already checked that out. The recommended answer put me on the right track that it was not an issue with permissions, I eventually solved it by disabling Chrome on my phone. I also never had this issue on 8.0/8.1.

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

In the end this was nothing to do with Android. I eventually just disabled the Chrome app on my test phone (Samsung S8) and it now works.

Comment: Ok,please try to mark it as an answer,  it will help others who have similar issue.