# Google Chrome ERR_CACHE_MISS workaround

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, google-chrome

Every time I navigate back to a page where I submitted a (post)form in Chrome, I get a white page displaying the following error: `ERR_CACHE_MISS`

I did some searching but couldn't find any real solution to this problem.

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19215637/navigate-back-with-php-form-submission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue using the trick. When POST data detected make another reload using header location (GET method). Back button is now redirecting to GET instead of POST and problem will not occure.

When U need to use posted data, simple store it into session for next aplication, when index.php is loaded again.

**index.php**

```
if (isset($_POST[...
{  
   // - 1st load

   $_SESSION["posted-data"] = $_POST;
   header('Location:index.php?pass=...');
}

if (isset($_SESSION["posted-data"]))
{
   // - 2nd load

   ... code to process ...
   unset($_SESSION["posted-data"])
}
```

After POST method the page is loaded twice, but when u parse in the begining of programm, it can not be noticed. You need only to organize data for double assembling. First - parsing incoming and prepare for transmiting after GET reload. (ie using SESSION).

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution but I used Javascript to prevent this error from appearing.

I added `history.replaceState({}, '', 'yourPage.php');` to the `onclick=""` attribute of the submit button, see this example:

```
<form action="yourPage.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="value" value="someValue">
    <input type="submit" name="sumitForm" onclick="history.replaceState({}, '', 'yourPage.php');" value="Pas aan">
</form>
```

What this does is it replaces the last page in your browser history with this page, so that when you navigate back `yourPage.php` will be called and the `ERR_CACHE_MISS` error does not appear anymore.

In case the current page could contain get variables you could use `history.replaceState({}, '', document.referrer);` instead.

Any suggestions/better solutions are welcome...

Comment: During the ERR_CACHE_MISS, the page isn't loaded, so you will not see anything, but this message.